# How can I assign an ephemeral port range to a specific linux service and not the entire IP stack

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, sshd

For example: If I want sshd to listen on 22 but use ephemeral ports of tcp 50-60 for communication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the client chooses the ephemeral port for the server to use;  in this example how would I tell the ssh client to use a specific ephemeral port?  The manpage is not clear on this matter.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't offer that option. There's BindAddress which only takes an address but not port (but it would be fairly easy to patch it to take a port as well, since it's just the same bind() call under the hood anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, because the server doesn't choose the ephemeral ports – the client (initiator) does. The initial TCP SYN packets received by sshd already have their ephemeral port filled in, and the server has no choice but to respond to the exact same port.